Use of probability/statistics in game theory
I've explored the literature on game theory, and I'm looking for a concrete application of probability or statistical inference to a game theory problem. To my surprise, a lot of literature in stochastic game theory doesn't really use much probability beyond calculated excepted utilities and Bayes' rule to define and analyze algorithms to compute equilibria and optimal strategies.
I've seen applications of RL to stochastic/Markov games, but I haven't really seen much literature that analyzes the behavior of random variables or uses more pure statistical inference techniques? Does anyone know of literature applying probability and statistics in this manner to stochastic games?
Edit: RL means "reinforcment learning"

What is RL? Edit your question please

RL means "reinforcment learning".

Hi  I'm not sure if you'll run into the same problem that you're having but, if you can get your hands on it, check out Cyert and Degroot's "Bayesian Analysis and Uncertainty in Economic Theory". There may be useful material in there or atleast references. I have it but it's in storage so I can't tell you whether it will help.

This looks interesting but unsure about it's usefulness in your case. https://ia600600.us.archive.org/7/items/mathematics_202103/Ebooks%20-%20Math%20-%20Mathematics%20Of%20Magic%20-%20A%20Study%20In%20Probability%2C%20Statistics%2C%20Strategy%20And%20Game%20Theory.pdf
